# Why my question has removed with in one day even they asked me revise?

Tags: support

My question has been removed from SE information security site even it's only within 12 hours and asked me to put on hold to revise.

**Time line:**

- I submitted my question yesterday around 16:00 JST on Feb 26.(JST)
- My question was put on hold to revise around 19:00 on Feb 26.(JST)
- I could see my contents to revise by 23:20 on Feb 26. (JST)
- My question has gone when to access from my Mac on 7:30 on Feb 27. (JST)

**Why I could know:**

Why I could know is that I checked my SE application with my smartphone when I wake up this morning. and I could not find my question with it which was put on hold to revise.

Even your site put on hold my question and asked me to revise my question. It's gone in this morning. You can see the screen shot as proof.

I have been having like gang stalker since last September they use microwave. This is the one of proof I'm facing the issue that is related to my question.

I removed my network cable before went to bed and check the answer of my question on my bed around 23:30. it was still there.

Please kindly let me know the reason as follows;
when was it removed my answer and provide the account and ip address.

Here is the screen shot of mine what I just open to view on my PC as proof. 
Please ignore the time stamp on the screen shot because it's taken this morning.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. Is it there now? (I can't see it.) Does your time range mean you think that's when it was deleted? In your profile, you can see your deleted questions. What does it say there about who deleted it and why?

Comment: Why do you ask this here and not on the IT Security Meta?

Comment: Questions that are too long, or have too many different sub-topics, are somewhat discouraged. What does "strange things on my body" have to do with IT security

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake I will ask this in IT security meta. Thank you for your advice

Comment: Should I delete this? if so, I will delete this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user3171796 - you have had guidance from various people telling you to read the [about] page, to structure your question into a **single** question and to stay on topic.

So far, you are not doing that. The question was so far removed from what we can allow here that it was even attracting quite disparaging remarks. We cleaned up what we could, and then realised that there very little that could even be on topic here.

Not a single one of your 8 points has **anything** to do with IT or information security.

This site is very focused on information security. Not anything outside this scope. Your question is not within scope. I don't know where you can go to get answers or help, but questions like this are not going to fit here.

Comment: ♦, I understand. If you know please kindly advice. Is there a place to ask about side channel attack. Or, Where should I ask to which site should I ask on SE?

Comment: Side channel attacks can be on topic on security attack exchange, as long as you follow the guidelines on [ask]

Comment: ♦, Thank you very much for your advice.